# Cloudera Manager and hdfs-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager

When using Cloudera Manager I can access to the hdfs-site.xml file via : 
Cloudera Manager > Cluster > HDFS > Instances > (NameNode, for example)> Processes 
COnfiguration Files > hdfs-site.xml

Then the URL points to : 
http://quickstart.cloudera:7180/cmf/process/8/config?filename=hdfs-site.xml

Is this file accessible directly via the file system and if yes, where is it located

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configurations set in the Cloudera Manager are stored in the Cloudera Manager Database. They are not persisted in the configuration files as in for other distributions.

On starting the service, the related configurations are passed as runtime configurations to the Cloudera Agent running on the node where the service is to be started. These passed on configurations are stored in the runtime directory `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/` of the agent.

Comment: Ok. Then what is the use of all the *-site.xml config files all over the file system (in the /etc/hadoop conf subdirectories) ?

Comment: They come as part of the package and are never used. All the configuration edits must be done in the Cloudera Manager.

Comment: What package ? CDH can be used without CM, so in that case these files are still relevant, arent' they ?

Comment: Yes, when they are used without CM. All configurations must be set to these files manually. Only when CM is in place, they aren't used.

Comment: Ok. One last question  please : Is it possible for CM and classic command line modes + conf files to co-exist, or once I go CM I have to forget about all the rest ?

Comment: Achievable but not recommended. Either one will start misbehaving if unexpected changes are made. It is better to stick with CM under suh conditions.